# How are NPT hole features defined?

Tags: modeling, technical-drawing

I'll be the first to admit that I have always been somewhat confused by best-practice dimensioning standards surrounding pipe threads. While there is a decent amount of literature available online, ([such as this](https://www.engineersedge.com/hardware/taper-pipe-threads.htm)) I still find the implementation to be a bit vague -- specifically regarding thread depth.

[ASME B1.20.1](http://esh-docdb.fnal.gov/cgi-bin/RetrieveFile?docid=3072&filename=Pages%20from%20B1-20-1_2013.pdf&version=6) (AKA *the NPT bible*) makes me think that one should callout thread-features such that they run to the "vanishing point" or L4. However, L2 is designated as the "maximum thread engagement distance".

In my experience, the engagement depth on NPT fittings can vary wildly (depending on quality of machining, amount of teflon tape used, and the person wielding the wrench, etc etc). This inconsistency can cause other issues when it comes to actually assembling -- but that's another topic in itself.

To summarize, my questions are...

1. **Which 'L-value' should I be using for thread depth when designing NPT fittings (i.e. in my cad model)?**
2. **If that value is L4, do machine shops know that I'm referring to vanishing point on my drawing and not max engagement depth?**
3. **Bonus: Are there any other 'best practices' surrounding this topic which may be useful?**

[image]

Comment: UPDATE: To complicate things even further, the default values that solidworks uses for NPT features is neither L2 or L4! It's approximately 104% of the recommended L2 depth -- in other words, slightly larger. How strange.

Comment: In industry , "go" and "no go" gages are the standards to  determine if the threads have the correct dimensions.

Comment: @blacksmith37 : Right, that makes sense. However, I'm really just wondering what dimension I should be using as my thread depth callout in cad. If I use L4, will the machine shop interpret that to mean threads should vanish at that depth?

Comment: (+1) Add pictures though. I like pictures.

Answer (score 1):

We are a bearing manufacturer. I design all the new special products that come in the door. We use NPT grease fittings in quite a few of our products. We use a 1/8 & 1/4 NPT grease fittings. As our standard practice we generally use a certified thread gauge and set our cnc to tap so the thread gauge will have a 4 to 4-1/2 turns max engagment. This has always worked for us and have never had a return in the 60+ years we have been in business. I have discussed this issue with our old school bearing designers and have learned in my 12 years with the company that this is a good way to measure. We have tested many different grease fitting brands and actual lubrication system fittings which all work great. I don't remember a time when we ever had a leak using this standard.

I think many times we get wrapped up in a ASME standard and forget that these guidelines are vague for a reason, they are meant to get us in the ballpark and we are suppose adjust until it works for our applications.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: Hey @sgwilliams, thanks for the input. That's really interesting that even the large-scale operations -- which use NPT consistently -- don't abide by a set in stone standard. When you say '4-4.5 turns max engagement', is that purely hand-tight? Or are you wrenching thread gauges down onto your parts? Not trying to come off sarcastic -- I actually don't know haha.

Comment: Thats a good question. Our procedure is just the light movement from turning the gage with your fingers. If we tried to torque down on the gage by performing hand tight it would wear the gage in a short amount of time and would need to be replace more frequently. We currently have all our measuring equipment certified/calibrated once every 3 months. Which we farm out to a 3rd party so there is no bias on whether or not the gage is calibrated correctly. The thread gages usually last a 5-10 years.